# MySQL: Apply ORDER BY on a field having datatype varchar

Tags: mysql

I have a db table like:

```
----------------------------
id  name        cat
============================
1   20.gif      logo
2   21.gif      logo
3   22.gif      logo
4   15.gif      web
5   16.gif      web
6   17.gif      web
7   23.gif      logo
8   18.gif      web
9   19.gif      web
```

and I want to fetch highest (latest inserted record for each cat) some thing like:

```
----------------------------
id  name        cat
============================
7   23.gif      logo
9   19.gif      web
```

for this I queried:

```
SELECT id, name, cat FROM portfolio GROUP BY cat ORDER BY name DESC
```

but because name field is an string so I cant apply ORDER BY on name.

any idea..?

Comment: I thing I have to use some REGEXP in my query but I don't know how :(

Comment: Can you pls explain what would you expect?

Comment: you must be doing something wrong. `order by` works for all..
try looking for some else error

Comment: @Abhinav Yap u r right let me think..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found the solution :

```
select id, name, cat from (select * from portfolio ORDER BY id DESC) AS x GROUP BY cat
```

I got help from [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Thanks to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) which really make developers life easy :)

Comment: just don't be surprised that implicit aggregation function "first record in a group" won't work in other RDBMS when using `group by`...

Comment: You are not ordering by name, but by id ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, cat 
FROM portfolio 
GROUP BY cat 
ORDER BY cast(substring(name, 1, INSTR(name, '.') - 1) as signed) DESC
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29009/1)

Comment: The `ORDER BY` doesn't perform sorting until after the `group by` is applied.